# Secure OAuth implementations in Android apps?

Tags: oauth

This may have a simple solution that I'm just not seeing, but Android apps can be decompiled, so people can extract your OAuth key and secret from your code. What is the best way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

All depends on your architecture. May be the best solution is not to place secret data in apps but better in service/server application. All what can be decompiled will be decompiled. You may only gain time for exctracting data from apps by means of encryption.